# Add a column to a gridview associated with an SQL data source [C#/ASP/Webform]

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my asp page which data comes from an SQL datasource (a stored procedure), I'm trying to find a way to add a column which is not in the datasource to the gridview: I would like to wether add an asp tag wich represents the column, make it invisible by default then programmatically make it visible or to directly create a new column in the code:

```
<vol:VlGridView ID="gv" DelayLoadPanelId="up" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" OnNew="gv_New" AbcTargetButtonId="btnSearch" AbcTargetFieldId="tbSearch" DataSourceID="sds" OnSorting="gv_Sorting" >
    <columns>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
    </columns>
</vol:VlGridView>
```

However I get the following error:

System.Web.HttpException: can't find the field 'CustomerID' in the selected datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a dummy column to the SQL query when using `boundfield` or autogenerated colums.

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, NULL AS CustomerID FROM table
```

In this case `CustomerID` is `NULL`, but you can specify other data types as well.

```
123 AS CustomerID
'stringValue' AS CustomerID
```

If you do not want/can't change the query, you can add a `TemplateField`

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            //stuff goes here
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid modifying my SQL query.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch data from database and store in datatable

//call SQL helper class to get initial data 
DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteDataTable("your_procedure");

dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID",  typeof(System.Int32));

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)

{

  // code to assign values to newly created column CustomerID

     row["CustomerID"] = 0; //assign value according to your requirement  
}

//then bind datatable to gridview
gv.Datasource=dt;
gv.DataBind();
```